# In $\triangle ABC$, if $AC=4$ and $BC=5$, and $\cos(A-B)=\frac{7}{8}$, find $\cos(C)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The problem is as the title suggests, in the given figure below, the goal is to find the Cosine of $\angle C$. I tried multiple ways of approaching this, such as with the Law of Sines, area formula, etc but none of them seemed to lead anywhere. My actual approach, which I will post as an answer below, uses the law of Cosines. Please share your own approaches especially if they use a different method!

[image]

Comment: Comforting when two answers with different methods give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Law of cosines works the Law of sines probably works. From $\frac{\sin A}{5}=\frac{\sin B}{4}=k$ and $\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)$ we get the equation $$\sqrt{1-25k^2}\sqrt{1-16k^2}+20k^2=\frac{7}{8}$$
and $k=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8\sqrt{2}}$. Hence, $\sin A=\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{8\sqrt{2}}$, $\sin B=\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{8\sqrt{2}}$, $\cos A=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{16}$, $\cos B=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}$ and
$$\cos C=-\cos(A+B)=\sin A\sin B-\cos A\cos B=\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{8\sqrt{2}}\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{8\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{16}\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}=\frac{25}{32}-\frac{3}{32}=\frac{11}{16.}$$

Note: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-sqrt%281-25k%5E2%29sqrt%281-16k%5E2%29%2B20k%5E2%3D7%2F8) output for Albert Chan's comment. Is this enough? I hope so.

Comment: Since we don't know angle A is acute or obtuse, we should solve k with ± in front of square roots. Then, we confirm it that indeed A is acute.  Or, just mention cos(A+B) does not produce 7/8, which implied A is acute.

Comment: cos(A)*cos(B) = cos(A-B) - sin(A)*sin(B). We square both side, to remove ±√ --> k^2=5/128. We use **RHS** for cos(A)*cos(B), with correct sign.  cos(C) = -cos(A-B) + 2*sin(A)*sin(B) = -7/8 + 2*5*4*(5/128) = 11/16

Comment: WA output I attached says if $A$ is obtuse there is no solution.

Comment: And questions are like girls. If you are finished with them you don't want to see their faces again. Please stop.

Comment: Also, from Goku's solution $\angle B\approx 52,3^{\circ}$ and since $\angle A-B\approx 29^\circ$ we have $\angle A\approx 81,3^{\circ}$, it is acute.

Comment: 2nd comment simply meant we don't have to care  A is acute or obtuse, if we use RHS.  cos(C) = -cos(A-B) + 2*sin(A)*sin(B), avoided worrying about sign of cos(A).  I'll stop now.

Comment: @albertchan oh İ see i am blind sorry. It is a self defense mechanism. I saw the trick now. -1+2=1. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my approach:

[image]

1.) First, we draw a line $AD$ from $A$ such that $\angle ABD=\angle DAB=\beta$, this means that $\angle DAC=\alpha-\beta$ ($\angle BAC=\alpha$). This implies that $AD=BD=x$.

Now, we know that:

$$\cos(A-B)=\frac{7}{8}$$.

We can apply the Law of Cosines in $\triangle DAC$:

$$\cos(A-B)=\frac{x^2+4^2-(5-x)^2}{8x}$$

$$\frac{7}{8}=\frac{x^2+16-25+10x-x^2}{8x}$$

$$7x=10x-9$$

Therefore, $x=3$.

Now, we can apply the Law of Cosines again in $\triangle DAC$:

$$\cos(C)=\frac{4+16-9}{16}$$

$$\cos(C)=\frac{11}{16}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can use [Law of Tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents)

Let $t_1 = \tan\frac{A-B}{2}$
Let $t_2 = \tan\frac{A+B}{2}$

$\displaystyle \cos(A-B) = \frac{7}{8} = \frac{1-t_1^2}{1+t_1^2}
\quad → t_1^2 = \frac{8-7}{8+7} = \frac{1}{15}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\tan\frac{A-B}{2}}{\tan \frac{A+B}{2}} 
=\frac{a-b}{a+b}$

$\displaystyle \frac{t_1}{t_2} = \frac{5-4}{5+4} = \frac{1}{9}
\qquad\qquad\quad → t_2^2 = 81×t_1^2 = \frac{27}{5}$

$\displaystyle \cos(C) = -\cos(A+B) = -\frac{1-t_2^2}{1+t_2^2} 
= \frac{27-5}{27+5} = \frac{11}{16}$

Comment: Nice thing about Law of Tangent, if all we need is numerical answer: cos(C) = -cos(2*atan((5+4)/(5-4)*tan(acos(7/8)/2))) = .6875

Comment: Break the law. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to solve for $\cos(C)$, by area calculations, done in 2 ways.

From Bob Dobb' answer, we have:

$\displaystyle \frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = 2R = \sqrt{\frac{128}{5}}$

$\displaystyle Δ = \frac{a\,b\,c}{4\,R} \qquad \qquad \quad
→ Δ^2 = \frac{125}{32}\,c^2$

Using my own [triangle area formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4610470/696342):

$\displaystyle z = \frac{c^2 - (a-b)^2}{4} = \frac{c^2-1}{4}$

$\displaystyle Δ = \sqrt{(a\,b-z)\,z} \qquad → Δ^2 = \frac{-81+82\,c^2-c^4}{16}$

Area squared calculations, done 2 ways, must match:

$\displaystyle \frac{125}{32}\,c^2 - \frac{-81+82\,c^2-c^4}{16} = \frac{(c^2-6)(c^2-\frac{27}{2})}{16} = 0$

$c^2=6 \qquad → \cos(C) = \frac{5^2 + 4^2 - 6}{2×5×4} = \frac{7}{8}$

$c^2=\frac{27}{2} \quad\; → \cos(C) = \frac{5^2 + 4^2 - \frac{27}{2}}{2×5×4} = \frac{11}{16}$

It is interesting we have 2 solutions for $\cos(C)\;$!
If we pick one solution for $\cos(C)$, the other is $\cos(A-B)\;$!

$\displaystyle \cos(A-B) = \frac{7}{8} \quad → \cos(C) = \frac{11}{16}$

Comment: FYI, c=√6, cos(C)=7/8, cos(A-B)=11/16, corresponded to  A ≈ 98.81°, B ≈ 52.24°, C ≈ 28.96°

Comment: Nice formula from Brahmagupta's... And it is like the first time I met "hav"....

Answer (score 2):

A novel way to solve the problem is to change the question, with equvalent answer.

$\cos(A-B) \;=\; \sin(A)\sin(B) \;+\; \cos(A)\cos(B)$
$\cos(\quad C \quad) \;=\; \sin(A)\sin(B) \;-\; \cos(A)\cos(B)$

Only difference between the two are the sign of cosine product term.
We change the question! $\; a=5,\; b=4,\;\cos(C)=7/8,\;\text{find}\;\cos(A-B)$

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2\,a\,b\,\cos(C) = 5^2+4^2-2×5×4×\frac{7}{8} = 6$

$\displaystyle 2R = \frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} 
= \sqrt{\frac{6}{1-(7/8)^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{128}{5}}$

Compare with original question, we have the same $R$

$\displaystyle \cos(A-B) + \cos(C) = 2\,\sin(A)\sin(B)$

$\displaystyle \cos(A-B) = -\cos(C) + \frac{2\,a\,b}{4R^2} 
= -\frac{7}{8} \;+\; \frac{2×5×4}{128/5}
= \frac{11}{16}$

--> Original question, $\displaystyle\;\cos(C) = \frac{11}{16}$

Comment: You may write a question instead.

Answer (score 1):

From $\cos(A-B)=\frac{7}{8}$, we have $\sin(\frac{A-B}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(A-B)}{2}}=\frac{1}{4}. {\tag 1}$

This is a nice property about interior angles: $$\sin(\frac{A-B}{2})=\frac{a-b}{c}\cos(\frac{C}{2}).$$ From this property and $(1)$ with $a=5$, $b=4$, we have $\cos(\frac C2)=\frac c4.\tag 2$
By using the half-angle formula $\cos C=2\cos^2(\frac C2)-1$, we have $\cos(C)=\frac{c^2-8}{8}.\tag3$
By using the law of cosines $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$ for the side $c$ and $(3)$ we can easily find $c=\frac{3\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}.$ And finally, by using $(3)$ again
$$\cos C=\frac{\frac{27}{2}-8}{8}=\frac{11}{16}.$$

Comment: For fun, we use the other Mollweide's formula.  **(a+b)/c = cos((A-B)/2)/sin(C/2)** → h = hav(C) = cos((A-B)/2)^2*(c/(a+b))^2 = (15/16)*(c^2/81) = c^2/86.4 → c^2 = (a-b)^2+4abh → 86.4*h = 1+80*h →  h = 5/32 = (1-cos(C))/2 →  cos(C) = 1-2h = 11/16