# In a triangle $\triangle ABC$, the sum of two sides is $x$, and their product is $y$. If $x^2-c^2=y$, find $\frac{r}{R}$ in terms of $x, c, y$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

This problem comes from a previous JEE Advanced examination, the problem is as follows:

> In a triangle $\triangle ABC$, the sum of two sides is $x$, and their product is $y$. If $x^2-c^2=y$ where $c$ is the third side, find the ratio of the inradius to the circumradius in terms of $x, c, y$

This is indeed a pretty challenging and tricky problem. Upon initial examination, spamming algebra seems to not lead anywhere. I found a solution using some angle chasing, which I'll share below, please share your own approaches as well!

Let $a+b=x$ and $ab=y$

We know that:

$$x^2-c^2=y$$

$$(a+b)^2-c^2=ab$$

$$a^2+b^2-c^2=-ab$$

Dividing by $2ab$ and exploiting the Law of Cosines, we can say that:

$$\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Now, this implies that $\angle C=120^\circ$

Now, using the Law of Sines, we get:

$$\frac{1}{2R}=\frac{\sin{C}}{c}$$

$$\frac{c}{2R}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

$$R=\frac{c}{\sqrt3}$$

We also know that:

$$\Delta= \frac{1}{2}ab\sin{C}$$

$$\Delta=\frac{\sqrt{3}y}{4}$$

Further, we can note that:

$$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$

$$s=\frac{x+c}{2}$$

Also, $r=\frac{\Delta}{s}$, therefore:

$$\frac{2\sqrt{3}y}{4(x+c)}=r$$

$$r=\frac{\sqrt{3}y}{2(x+c)}$$

Finally:

$$\frac{r}{R}=(\frac{\sqrt{3}y}{2(x+c)})(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{c})$$

$$\frac{r}{R}=\frac{3y}{2c(x+c)}$$

Comment: You introduce $R,\Delta,r$ in this calculation without defining them. From there on, the rest of your calculations are meaningless.

Comment: $R$, and $r$ have been defined, in the question title as well as the question itself. $\Delta$ itself is commonly known (by most people that are familiar with geometry) to represent the area of a triangle. @PaulSinclair

Comment: If you believe that's not enough, you're more than welcome to make a small edit to the post @PaulSinclair

Comment: You did not define $r$ or $R$ in either location. And you do not have the slightest idea what "most people that are familiar with geometry" know. The world is a much bigger place than you are pretending.

Comment: Like I said before, you're more than welcome to make that small edit if you feel that's necessary in order to answer this problem. That's all I'm going to say. @PaulSinclair

Comment: Maybe you could do a little better job may be on defining. Your work seems to be GOOD!

Comment: Your approach seems to be the only sensible one to me considering the seemingly arbitrary constraint from the problem is just equivalent to the much simpler $\angle C = 120$. After that, one can completely generally decude using your methods that $r / R = 2\sin(\angle C) \Delta / cs = ab\sin^2( \angle C) / cs$. Now you can plug in the value of $\angle C$ to immediately obtain the answer

Comment: Nice work. Just to confirm, the meaning of $R, r, \Delta$ is clear from context for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Law of Cosine, replace cosine with accurate [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab×\cos(C) = (a-b)^2 + 4ab×hav(C)$

Let $\displaystyle z = ab×hav(C) = \frac{(c-(a-b)(c+(a-b))}{4}$

$→ z = (s-a)(s-b)$
$→ (a\,b-z) = s(s-c)$

$Δ = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = \sqrt{(ab-z)\,z}$

If c is the smallest side, [(a-b) is exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterbenz_lemma), RHS area formula is very accurate.

---

Back to the oringal problem, without "angle chasing"

$\displaystyle z = \frac{c^2 - (a-b)^2}{4} 
= \frac{(x^2 - y) - (x^2 - 4y)}{4} 
= \frac{3y}{4}$

$\displaystyle Δ = \sqrt{(ab-z)\,z} 
= \sqrt{\left(y-\frac{3y}{4}\right) \left(\frac{3y}{4}\right)}
= \frac{\sqrt{3}\,y}{4}$

$\displaystyle \frac{r}{R}
= \frac{Δ}{s} ÷ \frac{a\,b\,c}{4Δ}
= \frac{4Δ^2}{s\,a\,b\,c}
= \frac{3y^2/4} {\left( \frac{x+c}{2} \right)y\,c}
= \frac{3y}{2c(x+c)}
$

Comment: My original derivation, h=hav(C) were used to get sin(C) --> Δ = (ab)*sin(C)/2 = (ab)*√(h*(1-h)) = √(z*(ab-z)). Area formula proved Heron's, not the other way around.

Comment: This is a really unique approach with haversine. You might just win the bounty with this one

Answer (score 6):

Let’s assume $S$ is the Area of the triangle and $P$ is half of the perimeter.

If $x=a+b$ and $y=ab$ $\\$ then $(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab=x^2-4y$.

We know that $S=\frac{abc}{4S}$ and $r=\frac{S}{P}$ then using the Heron’s formula we have:$$\frac{r}{R}=\frac{\frac{S}{P}}{\frac{abc}{4S}}=\frac{4S^2}{Pabc}=\frac{4(P-a)(P-b)(P-c)}{abc}$$
And also, $(P-a)(P-b)(P-c)=\frac{c-(a-b)}{2}\times\frac{c+(a-b)}{2}\times\frac{x-c}{2}=\frac{c^2-(a-b)^2}{4}\times\frac{x-c}{2}$ $$=\frac{c^2-(x^2-4y)}{4}\times\frac{x-c}{2}=\frac{3y(x-c)}{8}$$

Therefore $$\frac{r}{R}=\frac{\frac{3y(x-c)}{2}}{yc}=\frac{{3(x-c)}}{2c}$$

Which is consistent with [Goku カカロット](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1092912/goku-%e3%82%ab%e3%82%ab%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%83%88)
's final answer.

Answer (score 4):

Goku's solution with some geometric point of view:

1. Dropping a perpendicular from $O$, the circumcenter, to side $c$, we have $\frac{c}{2}=R\sin C=R\sin120^{\circ}$ and hence $R=\frac{c}{\sqrt 3}.$
2. Droping perpendiculars from the incenter $I$, to the sides $a,b,c$ we find:
   $a=r\cot\frac B2+r\cot \frac C2=r\cot\frac B2+\frac{r}{\sqrt3}\tag1$
   $b=r\cot\frac A2+r\cot \frac C2=r\cot\frac A2+\frac{r}{\sqrt3}\tag2$
   $c=r\cot\frac A2+r\cot \frac B2.\tag3$
   Now, $(1)+(2)-(3)$ gives $a+b=c+\frac{2r}{\sqrt 3}$ and hence $r=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}(x-c)$.

From 1 and 2, $$\frac rR=\frac{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}(x-c)}{\frac{c}{\sqrt3}}=\frac{3(x-c)}{2c}=\frac{3(x^2-c^2)}{2c(x+c)}=\frac{3y}{2c(x+c)}$$
which is, I mean the final expression I found as the answer is, not only consistent but looks exactly like Goku's final expression for the answer.

Comment: Another awesome approach, really like the geometric insight on this one. +1

Comment: Thanks. I was teaching, eh, they call so, from Coxeter-Greitzer's Geometry Revisited, book.